# Finding a element by attribute value in reference XML file

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0

I have this XSL:

```
  <xsl:template match="SongOpen|SongEnd">
    <td class="textItemWithPadding">
      <xsl:value-of select="//Labels/Song"/>
      <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
      <xsl:text> - </xsl:text>
      <xsl:value-of select="@Title"/>
      <xsl:variable name="ScripturesForSongs" select="document('ScripturesForSongs.xml')"/>
      <xsl:variable name="SongNumber" select="."/>
      <xsl:value-of select="$ScripturesForSongs/ScripturesForSongs/Song[@Number='$SongNumber']"/>
    </td>
  </xsl:template>
```

Example XML:

```
<SongOpen Title="Come to Jehovah’s Mountain" StartTime12="7:15" StartTime24="19:15" EndTime12="7:20" EndTime24="19:20">107</SongOpen>
```

The reference XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<ScripturesForSongs>
  <Song Number="1">(Adiyisɛm 4:11)</Song>
  <Song Number="2">(Dwom 83:18)</Song>
  <Song Number="3">(Proverbs 14:26)</Song>
  <Song Number="4">(Dwom 23)</Song>
</ScripturesForSongs>
```

The reference file goes down to 154.

I am trying to display the contents of the reference element by search using attribute.

Nothing is displaying.

### Got it!

```
  <xsl:template match="SongOpen|SongEnd">
    <td class="textItemWithPadding">
      <xsl:value-of select="//Labels/Song"/>
      <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
      <xsl:text> - </xsl:text>
      <xsl:value-of select="@Title"/>
      <xsl:variable name="ScripturesForSongs" select="document('ScripturesForSongs.xml')"/>
      <xsl:variable name="SongNumber" select="."/>
      &#160;
      <xsl:value-of select="$ScripturesForSongs/ScripturesForSongs/Song[@Number=$SongNumber]"/>
    </td>
  </xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<!-- Change your SongNumber variable to get the text of the SongOpen
     or SongEnd element.
 -->

 <xsl:variable name="SongNumber" select="./text()"/>

<!-- Also, note that the number in the OpenSong XML example, 107,
     does not map to any of the songs in the ScripturesForSongs XML.  -->
```

Comment: Thanks. I also found if I just removed the single quotes from around the `$SongNumber` that it would find it. Also, as explained in the question the XML is a snippet. There is a note saying it goes to 154. But thank you.